# What are the advantages of returning JSON response in Spring REST Using MappingJackson2JsonView Support over @ResponseBody Annotation?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am going through this [tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2015/02/20/spring-rest-hello-world-json-example/#) and found we can return JSON response in Spring REST Using `MappingJackson2JsonView` Support over `@ResponseBody` Annotation.

Apparently Using `@ResponseBody` Annotation is very simple and easy to implement where as Using `MappingJackson2JsonView` Support bit complex. Any way this is my personal opinion, but I want to know what are the **advantages of returning JSON response in Spring REST Using MappingJackson2JsonView Support over @ResponseBody Annotation**, if there is any? Can someone explain me which one is better between them and why? **When to use MappingJackson2JsonView Support and when to use @ResponseBody Annotation** for returning JSON response in Spring REST?

Comment: It seems to me that the author of the tutorial used MappingJackson2JsonView  as a way to easily demonstrate 'prettyPrint' (which was not always as trivial with ResponseBody but can also be done).  I hope you are provided a practical reason of when ResponseBody is not 'good enough'; I have yet to require anything more especially considering @RestController encourages its use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, MappingJackson2JsonView is good implementation.

But there is some advantages of ResponseBody.
With Help of @ResponseBody you can return object not as property 
For example

```
class Student extends ResponseDTO{
   publci String name = "John"
}
...
@ResponseBody ResponseDTO  getStudentInfo(){
  return new Student();
}
```

Result will be
    {
      "name":"John"
    }

With MappingJackson2JsonView you must return object in property like

```
{
  "student": {
               "name":"John"
             }
}
```

with @ResponseBody you can also return result with inline object extending

```
 @ResponseBody getStudentInfo(){
  return new Object(){
     public String name="John"
 };
}
```

But this is not good implementation

Some for good implementation MappingJackson2JsonView is good. But for more functionality like as return object or return ResponseDto, ResponseBody is more usefull

Answer (score 1):

I will say that even it's a bit harder to implement, good implementation can be more flexible and powerful than `@ResponseBody`.
For example:

`Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` provides a nice API to customize various Jackson settings while retaining Spring Framework provided default ones. It also allows to create `ObjectMapper` and `XmlMapper` instances based on the same configuration.

Both `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and `Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean` define a better Jackson default configuration. For example, the `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` property set to false, in order to allow deserialization of JSON objects with unmapped properties.

But in general, it's somehow the matter of own opinion and experiences.