# how can switch between modelandview or response body?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I want to develop one spring-mvc appication which will
also expose services using REST.

my question is how can use same contorller(current) methods to
produce service response?

how can switch between modelandview or response body?

Ex:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
    List<User> users = userService.findAllUsers();
    if(users.isEmpty()){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);//You many decide to return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

how can I make use of above method to return modelandview
as wel as responsebody as per the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MappingJackson2JsonView with Model model from [this tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-restful/spring-rest-hello-world-json-example/#) or @ResponseBody

MappingJackson2JsonView is good implementation than ResponseBody

But there is some advantages of ResponseBody. With Help of @ResponseBody you can return object not as property For example

```
class Student extends ResponseDTO{
   public String name = "John"
}
...
@ResponseBody ResponseDTO  getStudentInfo(){
  return new Student();
}
```

Result will be { "name":"John" }

With MappingJackson2JsonView you must return object in property like

```
{
  "student": {
               "name":"John"
             }
}
```

with @ResponseBody you can also return result with inline object extending

```
 @ResponseBody getStudentInfo(){
  return new Object(){
     public String name="John"
 };
}
```

But this is not good implementation

Some for good implementation MappingJackson2JsonView is good. But for more functionality like as return object or return ResponseDto, ResponseBody is more usefull.

I have answered a question like this in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35100582/1338215), there are also another answers